# How to select only specific active directory groups to sync with Sitecore

Tags: active-directory, sitecore

Let say the Active Directory have Group A, B and C.
How to specified like only Group A sync to Sitecore?

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: If this is not a programming question, then it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I believe you will have to clarify your question, what do you mean with sync? Do you mean that you have a process running the synchs users between sitecore and AD? I'd recommend switching your membership to use the AD instead then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get the members in a specific group, you can do this using a `customFilter`.

If for membership, you can add the following under your `membership` element in the web.config:

```
<add name="ad" 
type="LightLDAP.SitecoreADMembershipProvider" 
connectionStringName="ManagersConnString" 
applicationName="sitecore" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="1" 
minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
connectionUsername="user" 
connectionPassword="12345" 
attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" 
enableSearchMethods="true" 
customFilter="(memberOf=cn=test role 1,OU=CRM,DC=VM)" 
/>
```

Just ensure that you have a connection string configured for your AD, which would be something like: `<add name="ManagersConnString" connectionString="LDAP://testsrv/OU=Managers,DC=testdomain,DC=sitecore,DC=net" />`

And ensure that your custom filter gets to the specific group you're trying to allow access for.  I used LDAP Browser to navigate to my groups using a simple GUI and then copied the path.

See more in the [documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/11/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc66-70-a4.pdf) about customFilters in section 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify your group in the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings> 
 <add name="ManagersConnString" 
 connectionString="LDAP://testsrv/OU=Managers,DC=testdomain,DC=sitecore,DC=net" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

This example is copied from the [Documentation](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/11/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc66-70-a4.pdf) (see chapter 2.1.3). In this example, Managers is just a sample organization unit. But this is a normal LDAP connection string, so you can insert and filter there whatever you want.